# vatic annotation tool, on localhost I have an server error

Tags: video, webserver, apache2, mod-wsgi, mechanicalturk

[server error on localhost page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmCBk.png)

I applied this process:

```
$ mkdir /path/to/output/directory
$ turkic extract /path/to/video.mp4 /path/to/output/directory
$ turkic load test /path/to/output/directory Label1 Label2 LabelN
$ turkic publish --offline
```

[server error](http://localhost/?id=3&hitId=offline)

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the offline-parameter with load also:

```
$ turkic load test /path/to/output/directory Label1 Label2 LabelN --offline
```